# Setting Dynamic Ids In Kivy Through Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

Heyy guys,

I am trying to set a dynamic ID to a widget. The reason I am doing so is that I can find these widgets using the ID. Unfortunately, when I try to, I keep getting a `KeyError`. The reason I am doing this, si that I can create a new widget, upon dragging the current one, but have a dynamic iterative id on it, so its easy to keep track of.

The python code is given below:

```
iterations = 0


def widget_iterations():
    global iterations
    iterations += 1
    return iterations

class AddBlock(Widget):
    id = "add" + str(widget_iterations())

    def find_my_id(self):
        return self.id
```

The Kivy Language code is given below:

```
<AddBlock>:
    size_hint_y: None
    size: 110, 50
    pos: self.pos
    BoxLayout:
        id: root.find_my_id()
```

I also tried to use `self.find_my_id()`, `self.id`, `root.id`, but kept failing.

Finally, I am not sure about how to fix this.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set the id dynamically like this, it's not a property but a special token. You probably don't actually need to though, if you provide an example of why you think it's necessary then maybe we can suggest a better way.

Edit: This was too long for a comment:

The point of the id in kv is that the root widget of the rule gets a list of them by which to access the various widgets of the rule. If you define a widget in kv, it can't be dynamic in an important sense (since kv rules are just initial definitions that don't change) so you don't need a dynamic id. If you're modifying the children later then you don't need to mess with ids at all, since you must have references to the widgets already beacuse you specifically instantiated and added them. You can store that reference some other way to access it (you could also manually modify the ids dict if you wanted, though you don't have to).

If that's not clear, could you post a minimal working example of what you're trying to do and what you think should work, then I can explain by working with that?

Comment: We are trying to make an application similar to scratch (MIT's creation), where you can drag blocks. But we need to create these blocks, and keep track of where they are, and what they connect to. Thats why we thought that the usage of dynamic ids is necessary.